# fwrite() and fread() in mac os x lion is taking long time in case of a shared file between Linux device and Mac

Tags: c, macos, file, operating-system, fwrite

I have a simple Mac C program which writes data to a raw data file located on a USB device connected to a Mac computer. The raw data file is stored in the device which is FAT32 file formatted. The Linux C program which is running on the device opens the same file using `fopen()` and reads the same data written by the Mac program using `fread()`.

The `fread()` and `fwrite()` operations are too slow and take a long time to update.

Mac C program:

```
fp=fopen("/Volumes/Untitled/rawdatafile","rb+");

fcntl(fileno(fp),F_NOCACHE,1);
```

Are there any other APIs or flags to open file in shared mode?

Comment: Are you suggesting the USB device has an embedded Linux OS which is running at the same time? How do you mean slow - ms, seconds, minutes? You're kind of implying you want unbuffered direct I/O, but then fread()/fwrite() are generally buffered. Depending on what you're doing, however, it shouldn't be significant.

Comment: Huh?  Are you talking about reading/writing to the device from different computers at different times?  Or are you trying to access the device simultaneously from multiple OSes using virtual machines?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this safely.  You only haven't corrupted your data because you haven't run this for long enough.  On your USB device you must unmount the file-system when connected to USB, and not remount until the USB host (i.e. mac or pc) unmounts.

If you want to be able to read/write at the same time from the device and the host you have two main options:

1. Media Transfer Protocol
2. Pretend to be a network device and offer a link-local network share